# Content enity type: edit form not working

Tags: 8, entities

I have created a content entity form. Below is the code attached:

```
/**
 * Defines the mymodule entity.
 *
 * @ingroup mymodule
 *
 * @ContentEntityType(
 *   id = "mymodule",
 *   label = @Translation("mymodule"),
 *   handlers = {
 *     "view_builder" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder",
 *     "list_builder" = "Drupal\mymodule\Entity\Controller\mymoduleListBuilder",
 *     "views_data" = "Drupal\views\EntityViewsData",
 *     "form" = {
 *       "default" = "Drupal\mymodule\Form\mymoduleForm",
 *       "edit" = "Drupal\mymodule\Form\mymoduleForm",
 *       "delete" = "Drupal\mymodule\Form\mymoduleDeleteForm",
 *       },
 *      "access" = "Drupal\mymodule\RssFeedsAccessControlHandler",
 *     
 *   },
 *   links = {
 *     "canonical" = "/admin/config/search/mymodule/edit/{mymodule}",
 *     "edit-form" = "/admin/config/search/mymodule/edit/{mymodule}",
 *     "delete-form" = "/admin/config/search/mymodule/delete/{mymodule}",
 *    
 *   },
 *   base_table = "mymodule",
 *   admin_permission = "administer mymodule entity",
 *   fieldable = TRUE,
 *   entity_keys = {
 *     "id" = "id",
 *     "label" = "name",
 *     "uuid" = "uuid",
 *   },
 * )
 */
```

Here is my class with database table and form fields:

```
class Myclass extends ContentEntityBase  implements  ContentEntityInterface  {
    public static function baseFieldDefinitions(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
        $options_first = node_type_get_names();
        $fields['id'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('integer')
                ->setLabel(t('ID'))
                ->setDescription(t('The ID of the contact entity'))
                ->setReadOnly(TRUE);
        $fields['uuid'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('uuid')
                ->setLabel(t('UUID'))
                ->setDescription(t('The UUID of the contact entity'))
                ->setReadOnly(TRUE);
        $fields['name'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
                ->setLabel(t('Configuration Name'))
                ->setDescription(t('The Configuration Name of the rss entity.'))
                ->setSettings(array(
                  'default_value' => '',
                  'max_length' => 255,
                  'text_processing' => 0,
                ))
                ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
                  'label' => 'above',
                  'type' => 'string',
                  'weight' => -5,
                ))
                ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
                  'type' => 'string',
                  'weight' => -5,
                ))
                ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
                ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
        $fields['content_type'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('list_string')
                ->setLabel(t('Content Type'))
                ->setDescription(t('The Content Type of the Rss entity.'))
                ->setSettings(array(
                  'allowed_values' => $options_first,
                ))
                ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
                  'label' => 'above',
                  'type' => 'string',
                  'weight' => -4,
                ))
                ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
                  'type' => 'options_select',
                  'weight' => -4,
                ))
                ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
                ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
        $fields['langcode'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('language')
                ->setLabel(t('Language code'))
                ->setDescription(t('The language code of Rss entity.'));
        $fields['created'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('created')
                ->setLabel(t('Created'))
                ->setDescription(t('The time that the entity was created.'));
        $fields['changed'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('changed')
                ->setLabel(t('Changed'))
                ->setDescription(t('The time that the entity was last edited.'));

        return $fields;

    }
}
```

**My Routing.yml links are:**

```
mymodule.add:
  path: '/admin/config/search/mymodule/add'
  defaults:
    _entity_form: 'mymodule.default'
    _title: 'Add form'
  requirements:
    _entity_create_access: 'mymodule'

entity.mymodule.edit_form:
  path: '/admin/config/search/mymodule/edit/{mymodule}'
  defaults:
    _entity_form: 'mymodule.edit'
    _title: 'Edit form'
  requirements:
    _entity_access: 'mymodule.edit'
```

**Form gets created and values are submitted in database, which is fine. But when I click on edit link, form doesn't get open, instead only content type selected value get shown. 
Why I'm not able to edit/update form? Any suggestion where and what is being missed in creating content type entity form?**

Comment: Try to remove the canonical link

Answer (score -1):

The links should be different for canonical and edit:

```
 *     "canonical" = "/admin/config/search/mymodule/edit/{mymodule}",
 *     "edit-form" = "/admin/config/search/mymodule/edit/{mymodule}",
```

eg

```
 *     "canonical" = "/admin/config/search/mymodule/{mymodule}",
 *     "edit-form" = "/admin/config/search/mymodule/edit/{mymodule}",
```

Comment: Canonical and edit-form url can be same. canonical means default url. I'm setting default url to edit-form url..

Comment: What exactly do you get clicking on the edit link? An error, the entity view, a wrong form?

Comment: there are two fields in form, one is configuration name, other is select list of content type. I give config name "xyz"(say) and choose content type "article" and hit save. but when I click on edit link from table operations, it shows "article" written on whole page. No Form, No error just "article".

Comment: It looks like you go to the view of your entity instead of its form. Your routes are not correct defined, but from your code I cannot see where.